# How to fix the transfer of control bypasses initialization of error?

Tags: c++

I am creating a program which allows the user to input various information about pets and then stores this data in  a text file. It uses switch statements to switch between the selections. I am getting a transfer of control bypasses initialization of error (code E0546) upon compiling. How can I fix this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    int user_choice;

    cout << "\nManage Your Pet\n"
        << "  1. Create Pet\n"
        << "  2. Display Pet\n"
        << "  3. Delete Pet\n"
        << "  4. Exit\n"
        << "\nEnter your choice (1-4): ";
    cin >> user_choice;
    cout << endl;

    switch (user_choice)
    {
        string pname;
        string ptype;
        int page;
        string pcomment;

    case 1:

        ofstream fw("pet.txt", std::ofstream::out);

        if (fw.is_open())
        {
            cout << "What is your pet's name?" << endl;
            cin >> pname;
            fw << pname << '\n';
            cout << "What is your pet's type?" << endl;
            cin >> ptype;
            fw << ptype << '\n';
            cout << "How old is your pet?" << endl;
            cin >> page;
            fw << page << '\n';
            cout << "Enter a comment about the pet!" << endl;
            cin >> pcomment;
            fw << pcomment << '\n';
            cout << "Data stored!" << endl;
            fw.close();
        }
        else cout << "Problem with opening file";
        break;

    case 2:

        string myText;

        ifstream MyReadFile("pet.txt");

        cout << "What is your pet's name?" << endl;
        cin >> pname;

        while (getline(MyReadFile, myText))
        {
            cout << myText;
        }

        MyReadFile.close();
        break;

    case 3:

        string find;
        string line;

        cout << "Pet Name? " << endl;
        cin >> find;

        ifstream myfile2;
        myfile2.open("pet.txt");

        ofstream temp;
        temp.open("temp.txt");
        while (getline(myfile2, line))
        {
            if (line != find)
                temp << line << endl;
        }
        myfile2.close();
        temp.close();
        remove("pet.txt");
        rename("temp.txt", "pet.txt");
        break;

    case 4:
        cout << "Good-bye." << endl;
        break;

    default:
        cout << "We're sorry. \nYour choice must "
            << "between 1 and 4.\n"
            << "Rerun the program and try again."
            << endl;
        break;
    }

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't define variables inside a `switch`. Define all variables *before* the `switch`.

Comment: For future questions about build errors, please try to minimize the code you show. A [mre] should be the most minimal example possible that replicates the problem you ask about (without any other unrelated problem, always build and test it to make sure). Then copy-paste the full and complete build output of the shown code, into the question itself. And copy-paste it as text. Lastly add comments in the code where you get the errors.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude To be pedantic, sometimes you can (although you probably shouldn't). You just can't jump into the scope of a non-vacuously initialized variable.